# iPhone camera goes into DeskView with QR code reader app - RealtimeMediaSource error

Tags: ios, camera, vuejs3, qr-code, quasar-framework

I'm writing an app (Quasar, Vue3, Capacitor) which uses vue3-qrcode-reader plug-in.

This allows me to scan in a QR code, which it does, the first time on my iPhone 12 Pro.

The second time the camera goes to Desk View (Continuity Camera) and I can only reset it by re-loading the app.

Looking at the Xcode console on the second time I see the error messages:

> App[1745:620605] RealtimeMediaSource::selectSettings failed constraint 10

I've gone through the Info.plist (and most of the WWW) and found no clues.

I've also followed some advice about adding a line to config.xml without success.

Advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is only a problem for iOS version 16.3.

Upgrading to 16.4 fixed it!